# Replicate settings from one Ubuntu Desktop machine to another

Tags: openvpn, remmina, migration

I am setting up my second Ubuntu Desktop machine.

I would really like to copy some settings from the existing machine to the new one.  The following are the list of settings I've identified:

- Remmina
- OpenVPN connections
- Windows Shares (I think I figured this out -- copy the settings in /etc/fstab). I would then create them in *Files*.

Thanks.

PS: There isn't a tool that does this?

Comment: Most of these settings are user-specific and live in your home directory, in subdirectories starting with a dot `.`. The simplest way is to copy those directories that look important over to the other system.

Comment: Both machines have the same loginname (one is my laptop, the other is my desktop).  Is there a particular place I can look into.  While I would like to avoid it if the effort to seek transfer and get the files to work is considerable I will (grudgingly) redo everything

Comment: Applications on Ubuntu are free to store their settings in any way they choose. So there is no universal clone-your-settings procedure. What I do after installing a new system: copy the "dot folders" from my old system over to the new system, but in a separate place, say `/home/user/oldsystem`. That way, whenever I need my old settings for a newly installed system, I just need to copy them from `/home/user/oldsystem/` to `/home/user/`.

Comment: I will try this and share what happens

Comment: For Remmina the various endpoints are in /home/.local/share/remmina.  Copy these to the equivalen directory.

For each endpoint the credentials need to be reentered.

Comment: For AnyDesk I could not find the settings. I ended up recreating the endpoints.

Comment: You could backup your home directory using deja-dup and restore it to the new machine.